# Richtext Toolbar for GWT

Tags: gwt, richtext

Is there anywhere a ready to use "RichText Toolbar" for GWT?

It would be good if there would always be the source-code available, so that changes to the toolbar can be made easily.

Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend (second hit on google). But anyway: I'm maintaining a little project at google-code: [GWT RichTextToolbar](https://code.google.com/p/richtexttoolbar/). It can be used under the Apache2.0 licence and you can download all sources from there. It is easy to modify the project.

An explanation how to use this widget you will find on my [blog](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/de/gwt-toolbar-for-richtextarea-a-richtexttoolbar-with-html-editor/2010/02/).

The Widget is "standalone" and has no dependencies. I think it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a [RichTextToolbar](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/text/RichTextToolbar.java?r=4142) in his GWT code.

Comment: This Toolbar is not ready to use, since it has dependencies to other google-code.

Comment: You can refactor this toolbar and make it undependand from other google code.